# Volley sending data twice or more if web service error

Tags: android, android-volley

I have used volley in android. I have used Web Service to get data & send request.When Database shows error then volley send request again. I want send request only one time. If error shows, volley time out will be called..
I have used bellow code in android..

1. Bellow code I have used to send data to web service

   ```
    private void do_execute1() {
      pDialog.show();
       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
           new Response.Listener<String>() {
               @Override
               public void onResponse(String response) {
                   //pDialog.dismiss();


                   try {
                       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                       JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("testodes");

                       pDialog.dismiss();

                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           },
           new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                   pDialog.dismiss();
                   try {
                       if (error != null && error.getMessage() != null) {

                           Log.e("Error : ", error.getMessage());
                       } else {


                       }
                   } catch (Exception e) {

                   }
               }
           }) {
       @Override
       protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
           Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
           params.put("request_Code","");

           return params;
       }

   };
    //Begin set Time Out
    new VoleyErrorHandling(stringRequest);
    //End set Time out
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
     requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
   ```
2. Here is time out & maximum number of attempt

   ```
    public class VoleyErrorHandling {

      public VoleyErrorHandling(StringRequest stringRequest) {


         stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
           @Override
           public int getCurrentTimeout() {
               // Here goes the new timeout
               return 1 * 60 * 1000;

           }

           @Override
           public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
               // The max number of attempts
               return 1;
           }

            @Override
            public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

            }
        });


      }
    }
   ```

   How to solve it please help me..

Comment: Return The max number of attempts = 0  and run the the request please

Comment: @krishank Tripathi  it is working..thanks dear

Comment: why did i do not get the right answer or upvote ??? well  always happy to help